# How do I find out who is corrupting my memory?

Tags: windows-8.1, memory, drivers, bsod

**Question:** My Windows 8.1 media center is experiencing blue screens. Here's an excerpt from the most recent ones (sorry for the formatting, but superuser does not support nice tables):

```
Date        Bug Check                                Param 1            Caused by Address

2015-05-24  0x00000019  BAD_POOL_HEADER              00000000`00000020  Npfs.SYS+b872
2015-05-23  0x00000019  BAD_POOL_HEADER              00000000`00000020  ntoskrnl.exe+150ca0
2015-05-22  0x0000003b  SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION     00000000`c0000005  ntoskrnl.exe+150ca0
2015-05-21  0x00000050  PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA  ffffe000`83ffdff8  ntoskrnl.exe+150ca0
2015-05-21  0x00000019  BAD_POOL_HEADER              00000000`00000020  Ndu.sys+a49b
2015-05-20  0x0000001a  MEMORY_MANAGEMENT            00000000`00041287  ntoskrnl.exe+150ca0
2015-05-20  0x0000003b  SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION     00000000`c0000005  netbt.sys+23a4224
2015-05-15  0x00000019  BAD_POOL_HEADER              00000000`00000003  ntoskrnl.exe+150ca0
2015-05-15  0x0000003b  SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION     00000000`c0000005  ntoskrnl.exe+150ca0
2015-05-07  0x00000019  BAD_POOL_HEADER              00000000`00000020  WUDFRd.sys+7d1df000
2015-05-02  0x000000fe  BUGCODE_USB_DRIVER           00000000`00000006  USBPORT.SYS+2a64f
2015-05-01  0x00000019  BAD_POOL_HEADER              00000000`00000020  ntoskrnl.exe+150ca0
```

I've examined the minidump files with BlueScreenView and read the MSDN articles about the bug checks mentioned above. As far as I can tell, most of these BSODs mean:

- "Some kernel driver messed up your memory. Accessing this messed-up memory caused your system to crash. Unfortunately, I do not know *who exactly* messed up your memory, because that "messing up" might have already happened some time ago."

(If I am mistaken here, please tell me.)

Now the question is: **How do I find out *which driver* messes up my memory?**

---

**Details:** I've deliberately kept the question generic and asked about a debugging technique rather than the cause for *my specific* BSOD, so that the answers are useful for others as well. If anyone is interested in the particular details of my case: It's a x64 Windows 8.1 Shuttle XS35GTA V3 with a WinTV-HVR 930C adapter. I have discovered that I can *sometimes* reproduce the problem by watching live TV with Windows Media Center, turning the HDMI-connected screen off, turning it later back on and then closing Media Center. A few seconds later (after doing something else, e.g. starting or closing a web browser), the system will BSOD or just reboot.

Comment: First step is to ensure your RAM is good; memtest86 can help with this. Hopefully someone else has ideas on determining which driver is problematic, if that doesn't help.

Comment: @ChrisInEdmonton: Thanks. Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already did that: I had memtest86 run for a day without error.

Comment: Most commonly this kind of error is down to graphics card drivers. Can you track down some different versions and try them?

Comment: activate driver verifier: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff545448%28v=vs.85%29.aspx to get better dumps and look at them with windbg: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks

Comment: does DriverVerifier generates better dump outputs in Windbg?